# Open layer extension - longtouch

Tags: openlayers

I'm new in open layers and I'm trying to make some interactions with my map. I'm using ol extension like a longtouch and after some time i want to show fetaure on the map. It works fine with this extension but the problem is that it is shown after releasing the click.

Is there any way to show added feature on pointerdown event not after releasing the click ?.

Here I have an example. `http://viglino.github.io/ol-ext/examples/mobile/map.interaction.longtouch.html`

Comment: Does it need everytime to trigger the pulseFeature when clicked? Or do you want to trigger it only after sometimes and always create the point feature?

Comment: I want to create point feature only after sometimes and show it 
on the map immediately after the point feature has been added, not after releasing the click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is not on the interaction but on your vector layer. You have to set the `updateWhileInteracting` option for the layer if you want to reflect the insertion while interacting, otherwise the feature is added to the layer but only drawn when it finished (on mouse up).

I've updated the example to handle this case.

Answer (score 1):

It is really strange. I recoded the function to decompose and understand it. Even with it, the `Point` feature is only displayed after the `pulse` feature.

Here is my code :

```
map.on('pointerdown', function(e){
    timeOutVar = setTimeout(test(e), 1000);
});

map.on('pointerup', function(e){
    clearTimeout(timeOutVar);
});

function test(e){
    var point = new ol.Feature(new ol.geom.Point(e.coordinate));
    vector.getSource().addFeature(point);
};

var touchi = new ol.interaction.LongTouch(
{   handleLongTouchEvent: function(e){
    pulseFeature(e.coordinate);
    setTimeout( function(){ 
        pulseFeature(e.coordinate);
        }, 400);
    $(".options div").text(vector.getSource().getFeatures().length+" features added!");
            }           
    });
map.addInteraction(touchi);
```